# NancyFx will not display images

Tags: nancy

My last attempt: Don't even know what I'm doing anymore:

```
Get["/{any}/x.png"] = x => {
    return Response.AsImage(Program.portal.ourRoot + "x.png");
};

Get["/{any}/{moreany}/x.png"] = x => {
    return Response.AsImage(Program.portal.ourRoot + "x.png");
};

Get["/{any}/{moreany}/{extraany}/x.png"] = x => {
    return Response.AsImage(Program.portal.ourRoot + "x.png");
};
```

What I currently have in my ConfigureConvetions (in the BootStrapper).  I've tried a lot of permutations so far.

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions conventions) {
    //conventions.StaticContentsConventions.AddFile("x.png", ourRoot + "x.png");
    conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddFile("/portal/images/x.png", ourRoot + "x.png"));
    conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("images", ourRoot, new string[] { "png" }));
    conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/portal/", ourRoot, new string[] { "png" }));
    conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/", ourRoot, new string[] { "png" }));
    base.ConfigureConventions(conventions);
}
```

I have a CustomRootPathProvider that points to ourRoot (string, currently holds a direct C:\somepathstuffhere\ to a content directory).

I only need to serve a single image for my needs (at least, for now, things always tend to grow).  I'm using the directory structure as variables, so I need to be able to serve this image from a very large amount of locations.

I have a copy of the image in my root folder, and in a directory called images (the "images" has had '/''s all over it, occasionally even through the middle).  I am currently referencing the image with "/images/x.png", but I've tried from the root, just the name, and "images/x.png".

Thanks!

I will post back in the mean time if I figure it out (I'm assuming its something very simple.)

**Solved: Worked Around? \ Non-Optimal**

I changed my /images/x.png references to 'x.png', and then I dropped the extension reference to the following line.

```
conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/", ourRoot));
```

Nancy started catching the 'x.png' image for the Root Page and the \Portal\ page.  And then the 2nd Get /{any}/{moreany}/x.png started catching the rest of the 'x.png' requests (\Portal\Project).

I'm really not sure, why it started working all of a sudden.  I've just been playing the permutation game.

The big non-optimal part, is every single directory's version of the image is treated as brand new.  If anyone can solve this one for me, that'd be nice.  If I figure out what to do to fix it myself, I will post back with my solution.

**SOLVED**

This solution won't interest anyone familiar with web programming.  Its more of a *new user pitfall* situation.  When I started setting up NancyFX I read the documentation fairly thoroughly (even if I didn't get it all on the first read).  When I got to the web.config part, I first checked the Solution Explorer in VS and I didn't see one.  So I just went into my project directory and *created one* (And there-in lies the problem).  The one I made never applied settings to the project.

I figured it was a concept error, I just didn't know enough, to know where to look.\

Thx for the community's help! Hopefully my experience helps some other 1st time user out.

Comment: What do you mean by "will not display"? Are you trying to see the image in a browser or something else? Do you get any response from your routes? If so what's in the response?

Comment: I'm trying to see the image show up in a browser.  And with the exception of the root page, it won't load.

I'm been doing some programming for awhile, but I'm really new to web programming, so I'm inclined to think I got something conceptually wrong, but I don't know what concept of mine is wrong.

Comment: I have verified that the Get[] => x.png tests aren't even being called (they are the 1st routes).

Comment: how are you running the nancy app? E.g. are you hosting on asp.net running by hitting f5 in VS, or ... ?

Comment: Hitting F5 in VS (it's express?).  Does that cause problems?
Running it as a WebApp under OWIN ( I got all the OWIN specific alterations from the NancyFX website, I disabled, commented everything out, them all after it started "working", and nothing changed )

Comment: No, f5 should be fine. Can you share the complete solution?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see your additional comment (it was hidden under a link).  I got it working.  I now have a newer more interesting problem though, I'm using a reverse proxy Apache (my company uses Windows, vs. Linux, so no nginx), and Apache's html remapping still messes with serving an image due to it altering it's link ( so I can't just use a staticconvention for the same link\dir ), I've been trying to use the lambda method to just override the staticconventions, but I don't know how to write a proper Response that just always points to the same image *** I know sooo little ***